# Append list elements to a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
a = [(1, "X"), (2, 'Y')]
b = [(1, 'Z'), (2, 'K')]
c = [t[1] for t in b]

d = []
i=0
for element in a:
    d.append(element + (c[i],))
    i += 1

print d
```

Gives me my desired output
[(1, 'X', 'Z'), (2, 'Y', 'K')]

However this seems an unnecessarily long winded way of getting there. Is there a more efficient way (in terms of code) to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: The answer somewhat depends on the structure of `a` and `b`. Are the tuples always sorted and always indexed continuously from 1 up? If so, why? You could use simple lists in that case together with `zip()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
d = [x + y[1:] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Or [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
d = map(lambda x, y: x + y[1:], a, b)
```

`zip` creates a `list` of `tuple`s of correspondent elements in parallel iterables:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = [4, 5, 6]
# zip(a, b, c): [(1, 'a', 4), (2, 'b', 5), (3, 'c', 6)]
```

Comment: Brilliant! But it is quite difficult for me to comprehend how it is working.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Added some illustration. The actual example is a bit more complex because the elements of `a` and `b` are `tuple`s themselves.

Comment: Would this work if the lists were of uneven lengths? For example if I wanted to create a tuple structure based on the longest list length? (I am referring to the example you gave below the answer relevant to my problem.)

Comment: @MarcelKlockman Quote from the linked docs in the answer:  'The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence'. But then again, you will need some custom logic either way once you go beyond the shorter lists.

Comment: I understand zip, but what you did there with `+` is what confused (and still -ing) me!

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Ah, I see, `x` and `y` are both tuples, which can be concatenated via `+` (exclusively with other tuples).  `(1, 'X') + (1, 'Z')[1:]` then yields `(1, 'X', 'Z')`. The slice is needed to have a `tuple` `('Z',)` and not just `'Z'`.

Comment: That was great! You may want to add this info to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data structures seem a bit unusual, but here is one way to get to your result.

```
a = [(1, "X"), (2, 'Y')]
b = [(1, 'Z'), (2, 'K')]

a1, a2 = zip(*a)  # -> a1 = (1, 2); a2 = ('X', 'Y')
_, b2 = zip(*b)   # -> b2 = ('Z', 'K')

d = zip(a1, a2, b2)
```

`a1`, `a2` and `b2` are only necessary, because `a` and `b` themselves are rather cumbersome.

If the tuples in `a` and `b` are always numbered sequentially from 1, why have the index at all?

```
a = ('X', 'Y')
b = ('Z', 'K')

d = zip(a, b)  # -> [('X', 'Z'), ('Y', 'K')]
```

and if you need the index, you can always `enumerate()`:

```
for i, e in enumerate(d, 1):
    print i, e
```